# Html tag for setting Browser Mode and Document Mode in IE 10?

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser

I am wanting to set both Browser Mode and Document Mode in IE 10, in a programmatic manner and not by having to press F12 and then setting these manually.

I tried the following line, but its only setting Document Standards to 8, leaving the Browser Mode to 10.

```
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

[image: IE Compatibility Settings]

Comment: I do not really think you can set client's browser mode by any HTML. That feature is provided by a browser on demand

Comment: Ok. Can you put this in a separate post so I can mark it as an answer.

Comment: But that is what I know, its not that its surely the case. So I may be wrong, we should wait to see what anyone else has to say

Answer (score 1):

The browser mode has to be set before the document is requested, so it is not possible to set it on a per page or site basis. It can only be set in the F12 tool, by the user by clicking the compatibility mode icon, or by getting the site on Microsoft's compatibility list. See this link for further details: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/10/19/testing-sites-with-browser-mode-vs-doc-mode.aspx